# How get async method value from non async method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, asmx, webmethod

I have `async` method called `GetDetails();` to get data from API.

```
public async Task<string> GetDetails(string token, int tenantId, string fromDate,string searchText)
 {
    try
    {
        string serviceUrl = "http://localhost/Testapi/api/details/requestDetails/Details";

        //API callimg code going here....
        
        var response = await client.PostAsync(serviceUrl, content);
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        client.Dispose();
        return result;
    }
}
```

I need to get above `async` method data. So I tried do it as follows,

```
public string GetAllDetails(string token, int tenantId, string fromDate,string searchText)
{
    var dataResult = GetDetails(token,tenantId,fromDate,searchText);
    return dataResult;
}
```

But I can't call `GetDetails` async method from non async method. Have any other way to do this? I can make that `GetAllDetails()` method as async, because it calling from web method as follows.

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public string GetDetails(string fromDate,string searchText)
{
    try
    {
        SessionState session = new SessionState(Session);
        DetialsConfiguration dc = new DetialsConfiguration();
        string details = dc.GetAllDetails(session.JwtToken, session.ClientId,fromDate,searchText);
        return details;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.LogErrorEvent(ex);
        throw;
    }
}
```

How can I get `GetDetails()` API response data to my web method? Please help me to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call asynchronous method from synchronous method in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343594/how-to-call-asynchronous-method-from-synchronous-method-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

> How get async method value from non async method

You don't... unless you have a very specific use case. Instead you let the *async and await pattern* propagate

```
public async Task<string> GetAllDetails(string token, int tenantId, string fromDate,string searchText)
{
    var dataResult = await GetDetails(token,tenantId,fromDate,searchText);
    return dataResult;
}

...

[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public async Task<string> GetDetails(string fromDate,string searchText)
{
    try
    {
        SessionState session = new SessionState(Session);
        DetialsConfiguration dc = new DetialsConfiguration();
        string details = await dc.GetAllDetails(session.JwtToken, session.ClientId,fromDate,searchText);
        return details;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.LogErrorEvent(ex);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Also note any `async` methods should have the Async Suffix E.g `GetAllDetailsAsync`